# tcpdump (-i any) with vlan

Tags: vlan, tcpdump

I have a question regarding tcpdump (capturing all interfaces) and a strange capture I see.

Environment:

2 Linux devices connected and configured with VLAN TAG (802.1q). I am pinging between the 2 device vlan interfaces, network wise everything works well. When using tcpdump to capture all interfaces `tcpdump –i any –n –e`.

I am seeing this:

The first 3 packets looks fine

Received on the main interface (tagged):

> *-6:-45:-40.2216  In 00:11:22:33:44:56 ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 104: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 10.0.0.10 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP
>   echo request, id 2452, seq 487, length 64*

Received on the vlan interface (untagged):

> *-6:-45:-40.2217  In 00:11:22:33:44:56 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.0.0.10 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 2452, seq 487, length
>   64*

Sent from the vlan interface (untagged):

> *-6:-45:-40.2221 Out 00:11:22:33:44:55 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.10: ICMP echo reply, id 2452, seq 487, length
>   64*

**But the fourth sent from the main interface looks erroneous:**

> **-6:-45:-40.2223 Out 00:11:22:33:44:55 ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 100: vlan 1280, p 2, ethertype Unknown, LLC, dsap SNA (0x04)
>   Group, ssap Unknown (0x3e) Response, ctrl 0x0000: Information, send
>   seq 0, rcv seq 0, Flags [Response], length 80**

When defining the specific interface (eth0 or eth0.10) to tcpdump it looks well:

> "tcpdump -i usb0 -n -e"
>
> *-6:-13:00.40042 00:11:22:33:44:56 > 00:11:22:33:44:55, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 102: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 10.0.0.10 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 2452, seq 2442, length 64
>   -6:-13:00.40100 00:11:22:33:44:55 > 00:11:22:33:44:56, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 102: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.10: ICMP echo reply, id 2452, seq 2442, length 64*
>
> "tcpdump -i usb0.10 -n –e"
>
> *-6:-52:-14.5791 00:11:22:33:44:56 > 00:11:22:33:44:55, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.0.0.10 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 2452,
>   seq 94, length 64
>   -6:-52:-14.5795 00:11:22:33:44:55 > 00:11:22:33:44:56, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.10: ICMP echo reply, id 2452,
>   seq 94, length 64*

Currently, I work with an usb network interface but the same goes for Ethernet (eth0 / eth0.10).

The extra 2 bytes when using `–i any` are because Linux adds its Linux cooked 2 bytes.

Any idea, why does tcpdump shows this line when using `–i any` ?

Since traffic is working well, I guess it is just a parsing issue with tcpdump ???

> ***-6:-45:-40.2223 Out 00:11:22:33:44:55 ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 100: vlan 1280, p 2, ethertype Unknown, LLC, dsap SNA (0x04)
>   Group, ssap Unknown (0x3e) Response, ctrl 0x0000: Information, send
>   seq 0, rcv seq 0, Flags [Response], length 80***

Comment: Forgot to mention: tcpdump version 4.4.0
libpcap version 1.4.0 Kernel 2.6.35.12

Comment: I think this would be better over on http://www.ServerFault.com It seems the answer will require more knowledge of the software on those Linux boxes, than knowledge of networking.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think tshark can cope with [cooked capture](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SLL) today, I rarely if ever use tcpdump anymore.

Back when tshark couldn't cope with this (when I was capturing ERSPAN) I wrote [script](http://ytti.fi/pcapop) which can pop N bytes out of each frame, quite useful also if you're tunneling over something which is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years later.... :D

I have run into the same problem.

With hours of tcpdump and wireshark, I have figured out what the problem is, or what I have done wrong.

After the VLAN tagged (from this point of view, tag value is not important) packet is received and sent towards, I (the switch program I have written) accidentally forgot to add the respective VLAN header to the packet header, however Ethernet.etherType was still 0x8100 (VLAN's ETHERTYPE). This means that after the Ethertype, application (in our case `tcpdump/wireshark`) was expecting a 4-byte VLAN header but the IPv4 header was coming.
Since IPv4 starts with 4 bits of `version` (set to 4), 4 bits of `header length` (which if normal IPv4 packets are considered, e.g., 20bytes, is set to 5), then comes 8 bits of `diffserv`, etc., e.g., IPv4 header starts with `0x4500...`

This means that the first 4 bits are considered as a 3-bit wide `VLAN PCP`, and a 1-bit wide `VLAN DEI` (this is `0x4` in our simple IP packet), then the remaining 12-bits will be the `VLAN VID`, which is `0x500` from the simple IP packet resulting in a mistaken `1280 VLAN VID (int('0x500',16) = 1280)`.

I hope it helps.